# Пропуск ввода переменной

Tags: c++

скажите пожалуйста как можно пропустить ввод целочисленной переменной в с++ Пример: Запускается консоль, пользователь вводит первую переменную.Нажимает Enter, если не хочет вводить вторую переменную, то опять нажимает enter  и программа продолжает работу дальше.

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int N1;
     int N2;
     cin >> N1;
     cin >> N2;
 }
```

Comment: Вводите строки. Если строка пустая - значит, нажат Enter, нет - читайте число из введенной строки...

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите функцию [std::cin.ignore()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Comment: Как это может помочь?

Comment: @AnT, похоже что когда я давал ответ, был не совсем в адекватном состоянии =)